# Cannot Define Global Variable that used in one class Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, variables, global-variables

I tried to make a global variable that can used in some function in one class.
I dont know why, when this class called, variable $batch not defined. I have followed some tutorial in the internet but my global variable doesnt work.

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\DataTmp;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class ImportDataTmp implements ToModel
{

private $batch;

public function __construct()
{
    $model = DataTmp::latest('input_batch')->first();
    if($model->input_batch == 0) {
        $this->$batch = 1;
    } else { 
        $this->$batch = $model->input_batch + 1;
    }
}

public function model(array $row)
{

    return new DataTmp([
        'nim' => @$row[0],
        'id_level' => @$row[1],
        'input_batch' => $this->$batch
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: `$this->batch` ...

Comment: Change `$this->$batch` to `$this->batch` remove extra `$`

Comment: thanks, why I didn't see this before . lol